# Datagridview column SUM to textbox & update textbox with each adding row

Tags: c#, datagridview, sum, multiple-columns

I'm new to C# & i need your help with my below problem.
I've DGV & its not bound to any data source. I have few textboxes & datetimepicker to add data to DGV. Once the user press the "ADD" button in my form it will add new row to the DGV. My problem is i need to get the SUM of column 4th in my DGV in to a textbox in my form which is the total bill value. And it should be updated with each adding rows column 5th values

Hope you guys understood my problem. Sorry for my bad English. any codes are welcome.

```
textBox10.Text = "0";
           foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvFE.Rows)
           {
              int n1 = row.Index;
              textBox10.Text = (Double.Parse(textBox10.Text.ToString()) + Double.Parse(dgvFE.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value.ToString())).ToString();


           }
```

I have entered above code under "ADD" button click event. But my textbox10 is showing only first line of bill value. not the SUM of all rows in column 5th. (User can add more columns as i mentioned earlier.)

I have try below code under the same button click event but the result in textbox10 is same like above code.

```
int sum = 0;
for (int x = 0; x < dgvFE.Rows.Count; x++ )
{
  sum += Convert.ToInt32(dgvFE.Rows[x].Cells[4].Value);
}
```

Please help.

Comment: It should be Cells[3] if you are trying to access the value in your 4th column.

Comment: Hi Vindula, Sorry i've mentioned it wrong. Column is 5th & cells[4]. Question updated. Can you help me out?

Comment: Vindula, I just found the answer. SUM code should be entered under DataGridView.CellValueChanged event. Thanks.

Comment: Great, yeah it makes sense to use the CellValueChanged event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears from your post that the application user is going to enter data into the grid manually. If so, using the Add button click event is not the right place to update the total.

I assume you are adding a new row when "Add" button is clicked. It is just a new row and it is not going to have any data. When user enters data, the event has already processed and `textbox10` is not going to get updated.

You should use `DataGridView.CellValueChanged` event to update your column total.

Code Sample:

```
    void dgvFE_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 4)
        {
            textBox10.Text = (from DataGridViewRow r in dgvFE.Rows
                             select Convert.ToDouble(r.Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value))
                             .Sum().ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Ravi, Thanks for the comment. Yes you're absolutely correct. I have added my second code under the DataGridView.CellValueChanged event & it works. First code is not working as it throws NullReferenceException. Error is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."